# cakephp211 css issue (not correctly used)

Tags: cakephp-2.1

in my ctp file i have this:

```
     <div class="sponsor">Image
           <?php    $this->Html->image('banner.jpg', array("alt" => "banner"));?>
     </div>
```

and this is a css class:

```
         .sponsor {
            margin: auto;
            width: 728px;
            padding-top: 0px;
            padding-bottom: 15px;
            text-align: center;
               }
         .sponsor img {
            margin-top: 5px;
               }
```

but i don't have the correct result, image don't appear. i think class (div class='sponsor') sponsor in css file is not correctly understood by cakephp, while keyword 'id' in 'div' is correctly used.
so how i can solve this?
thanks men.

Comment: ok! the parade that i found is to replace keyword 'class' by 'id', and '.sponsor' by '#sponsor'. but if you have many class with the same name and want to change all of them by 'id', you got to consider each time differents id names.thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to `echo` your helpers to make them output things! ;)